# Sony Camera Remote API loop minimum

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Can I Record a loop that is smaller than 1 minute?

The api just says that the JSON gets minutes.

Comment: What happens if you pass it 0.5 minutes?

Comment: I am researching this Tec at the moment.
I have not written any code till now.

Comment: Would you add a link to the relevant part of the Sony API docs in your question? This feels a bit brief and unresearched at the moment.

Comment: [link](https://developer.sony.com/downloads/all/sony-camera-remote-api-beta-sdk/) 
The whole api is here. There is no Internet Doc with links.